# Corrupted Default WinXP Partition

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

Here's a longer explanation... I had WinXP already installed on my computer with no partition except for that one. I made a 20 GB unallocated partition using the [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) program, then  using a [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) (FreeDOS is an MS-DOS compatible OS) disk I made, I installed it onto the unallocated space. When it had finished, I restarted my computer surprised to find it say, "*Error, corrupted operating system*" I then came up with the idea of deleting the DOS partition and installing WinXP a second time onto the partition. I did that, booted into the new XP, and from there I could view all my files on the other partition except the ones which are locked by my old user. I don't want to just access them I want to actually boot into that partition because I know it's still there. It just won't come up on the startup screen when it asks you which partition do you want to boot into. Because I have programs that I bought and just opening them from the second partition, won't open them in the full paid-for version.

**How can I fix my default partition and boot into it?  What can I do to fix the 1st/default partition and make it viewable in the partition select screen when you first turn on your computer?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Randolph West I made my question bold, sorry I guess I didn't really have a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about windows user personal folder such as my documents, Desktop etc, It's just an security issue and you can access these folders by changing there ownership.

To take ownership of a file, follow these steps:

> Right-click the file that you want to take ownership of, and then
>   click Properties. Click the Security tab, and then click OK on the
>   Security message (if one appears). Click Advanced, and then click the
>   Owner tab. In the Name list, click Administrator, or click the
>   Administrators group, and then click OK.

Please have a look for Microsoft artical at [HERE...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421)

One more thing, If your folder are locked by any third party application such as "Folder lock" etc. Then you have to need to contact support for application provider.

Comment: I made the explanation longer and hopefully clearer, please help me!